# Ajax link to run codeigniter controller then update html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Sorry for the most simplest of questions but I can't seem to get anything to work. It's the first time I've really played around with AJAX.

I'm developing in codeigniter and I have a link that when clicked runs the controller: photo function: like and allows the logged in user to like the photo then redirects the user back to the photo and displays a slightly different version of the button showing that the user likes the photo.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('photo/like'); ?>/<?php echo $photos['id'];?>" class="uk-button <?php if ( $liked == '1' ) : ?>uk-icon-heart uk-button-danger<?php else: ?>uk-icon-heart<?php endif; ?>" data-uk-tooltip title="<?php if ($liked == '1'):?>Likes<?php else:?>Like<?php endif; ?>"> <?php if ( $like_count > '0' ) { echo $like_count; } ?></a>
```

It works fine but I thought it would be cool to replace it with an ajax function so it's more of a fluid motion instead of navigating off the page and then back again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".uk-button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Here you can add your ajax
    $.ajax({
     url: site_url + 'photo/like',
     data: { 
      liked : 1
     },
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     async : false,
     success: function(success_record) {
       console.log(success_record,":success_record");
       //You might receive your like count from PHP here
     }
    });
});
```

In your success record you would get your PHP record values. Based on that you can increment or decrement count in success function

Comment: If you wish to add any parameter like "image name" or "uid" or "current like count" you can pass accordingly in that data as json

Comment: Thanks Makrand i'm trying your solution out and i'm getting a site_url not defined. 

Also my controller is getting the user information from the variables passed in the url. Does this mean I would need to rewrite the controller to look for POST objects instead?

Comment: @Tristan you can use base_url if its codeigniter but you will need to define it in your header script tag. Not major changes are required in your controller apart from getting the "post" variables. Sorry fo the delay

Comment: could friendly urls have anything to do with it. I just updated the url with the url and im getting an 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: You can test if the url is an issue by putting the url as this : "http://localhost/your_project_path/photo/like". I am assuming photo is a controller and like is a function within it.

Comment: Yes the like function is within the photo controller. for some reason i'm getting a POST 500 internal error.

Comment: well specifying the project path/controller/function should do it. or else include this in your header file : <script type="text/javascript" >var base_url = "<?php echo base_url()"; </script> and then form URL in AJAX as : base_url + 'photo/like'

Comment: Just tried that. this is the error i'm getting 

`POST http://localhost/photo/like 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.10.1.js:8724
send jquery-1.10.1.js:8724
x.extend.ajax jquery-1.10.1.js:8154
(anonymous function) 118:240
x.event.dispatch jquery-1.10.1.js:5116
v.handle`

Comment: you are missing your site name (project name) its should be : localhost/your-site-name/photo/like

Comment: base_url wont be accessible in Js thats why i had recommended before that you put it in a script in your header and then use base_url + 'photo/like' in url

Comment: I've put this ` var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"; ` just above the ` $(".like-button").click(function(e) {` line

Comment: that won't work you will need to add it in any view which is loading initially. put a script in that view and the code in it and you job will be done

Comment: maybe you put it before jquery loads. change the position

Comment: :( well the above AJAX code is definately working. for the time being copy paste url from browser address bar and get the ajax running

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.likeLink').on('click', funciton()
    {
        var obj = $(this);
        var id = obj.attr('id'); //anything you want to pass to update your like somewhere

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'YourFilePathWhereYouWillDoTheLike',
            data:
            {
                id: id,
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(response)
            {
                obj.html("You have liked this!");
            }
        });

        return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks nsk. do I need to pass data as post type. at the moment i'm just passing the image id in the link url?

Comment: you can pass whatever you want, whether image url or id through data:{  imageUrl : "theUrlHere", imgId: id}

Comment: and yeah, its a post, you retrieve it as $_POST["imageUrl"].